# How do I get ISO 3 Amount from given currency?

Tags: c#

I am working with an API that expects currency to be multiplied by ISO 3 code.

Given I have a table that gives me the values for ISO 4217 as follows:-

```
CURRENCY, DECIMAL
JOD         3
AED         2
 and so on.
```

and for example: If the amount value was 500 AED; according to ISO code 3, you should multiply the value with 100 (2 decimal points); so it will become 50000.
Another example: If the amount value was 100 JOD; according to ISO code 3, you should multiply the value with 1000 (3 decimal points); so it will become 100000.

Given I have the amount 500 and knowing the decimal for AED is 3 how do I get the 50000?

My approach is as follows but don't think its right.

```
decimal amount = 500m;
int decValue = 3;
var decimalAmount = (amount * decValue * 100); //50000
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V7ARLT

Answer (score 1):

You need to use powers.. [`Math.Pow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-5.0)

> Returns a specified number raised to the specified power.

`10` to the power of `1` is `10`

`10` to the power of `2` is `100`

etc...

**Given**

```
static decimal Convert(decimal amount, int places) 
   => amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, places - 1);
```

**Test**

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert(500, 1));
Console.WriteLine(Convert(500, 2));
Console.WriteLine(Convert(500, 3));
```

**Output**

```
5000
50000
500000
```

<sub>***Note**: This is assuming your description is right*.</sub>

> Given I have the amount `500` and knowing the decimal for AED is `3` how do I get the `50000`

If it's not, you might need to remove the `- 1`.